# How can I push to a git-svn repo?

Tags: git, git-svn

I cloned an svn repo with `git svn clone ...` and now I want to push changes to it. after that I will use this repo to rebase everything and commit back to svn. The problem that pushing to a non-bare repo seems to not be a good idea, and git svn seems unhappy about working with a bare one?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use an intermediate bare repo. After all, pushing to a repo with which you work is not a good idea. You can also pull to it instead of pushing if this option is available.

Comment: Don't understand this answer.  1. *Why* is "pushing to a repo with which you work"  not a good idea?  2. How can you "pull to" something?

Comment: 1. because then you will need to sync the working copy with pushed commits manually. 2. with `git pull`